# Save a copy window to send document in entered email is not working in In-Person DocuSign process. Not received any email

Tags: docusignapi

We are implementing the DocuSign in our application. While signing the envelope in In-Person mode there is an window (popup) to send a copy of the document in an email. 
We have entered the email but no email received. Checked settings in the DocuSign portal account but not able to find any setting for this.
Please let us know how to enable the save a copy email in DocuSign.

Answer (score 0):

I would check settings on your side if you are not receiving the emails.  Things like security software, spam/junk mail filters, firewalls, etc. that might stop the email from arriving.  DocuSign is a widely used platform, if the emails weren't going out it would be publicly known very quickly, and I just tested this myself and I'm getting the emails.  I might suggest you call their support department...